# What's the appropriate layout for academic or scientific articles

Tags: formatting, article, journal, layout, research

I want to step up my game and produce more professional written assignments, research articles, etc. and I'm looking for a more suitable style/layout appropriate for the sciences and general academia.

Comment: If you are interested about publishing in a journal, then, most journals have their specific requirements/expectations about the output and some/many of them provides their own (or a requested) template (or a specific format you have to follow). If you want a "suitable/appropriate to you" instead, just keep in mind that as simpler and standard code you use so more modifiable and adjustable the format is (in order to be able to adjust it for future publications). For example an `article` or a `report` `\documentclass` (depending on the need of chapters or not) could be a perfect start.

Comment: I admit to a certain bias here ... `amsart` is the basic style used by most of the journals published by the American Mathematical Society.  The main difference between the various journals is the logo placed in the upper left-hand corner of the first page, but that shouldn't matter to you.  The document class and associated material is included in TeX Live and available from CTAN.

Comment: Explaining my comment by  respecting @barbarabeeton's comment (and not only). I have converted many documents to get them ready for publishing in several journals. Many of them asks to use their template. Others have just some expectations on the format of the references or asks for example to use an appendix to include all the figures and tables and let them add it in the final article. If you follow the specific journal's requests, then you have almost to rewrite the code from scratch to publish in a different journal. So, use a standard `documentclass` (may be `amsart` too) to avoid that.

Comment: Since @koleygr has mentioned using a "standard" document class, it's a fact that `amsart` was carefully developed to recognize as closely as possible the same input that works with `article`, except for the top matter (title, author, addresses, etc.), where the identification of these elements in `article` provides insufficient information to meet the requirements of cataloging organizations.  So to switch from `article` to `amsart`, only a few minor and well defined modifications are required.

Comment: I should clarify, I'm an undergrad. I'm not actually submitting articles to journals at the moment, I just read a lot of them, and want to achieve that same kind of professionalism with the papers I submit to my professors. Until now I really only used LaTeX to draw standalone diagrams. I don't really know how to get a proper article style layout.

Comment: @tjt263 ... You should start just using LaTeX and you will find out this way that it already provides a professional layout. By using it more and more you will find here answers for specific format (and not only) changes and you will learn to use it your own way to get as far as you can afford (in order of effort but of joy too).

Comment: Another standard of sorts is IEEEtran.  Check wikipedia for style guides.